# why is this code not working--django paginate

Tags: django

I'm trying to paginate a page in order to display 1 status per page...it fails to paginate and it doesn't display the link to the next pages

views.py

```
def post_list(request):

        posts= Post.objects.all()
        paginator = Paginator(post_list, 1)
        page = request.GET.get('page')
        return render(request, 'news.html', {'posts':posts})
```

templates

```
{% for num in posts.paginator.page_range %}

    {% if posts.number == num %}

        <strong>{{ num }}</strong>

            {% else %}


           {{ num }}


        {% endif %}             

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: from what you've shown, `paginator` is not part of `posts` so `posts.paginator` is bound to fail

Comment: this exact code is working for instructor

Answer (score 0):

`posts` is still the `Post.objects.all(..)` queryset, you still need to retrieve the page with [**`.get_page(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/paginator/#django.core.paginator.Paginator.get_page):

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator

def post_list(request):
    post_list = Post.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(posts, 1)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    posts = paginator.get_page(page)
    return render(request, 'news.html', {'posts':posts})
```

Without making a page, you do not do much more than just constructing a pagiantor, and then throw that away.

In your template, you can thus render this as:

```
<strong>{{ posts.number }}</strong>
```

Comment: @Abeselom: exactly what is `posts.number`. `posts` is a *queryset* (a collection) of `Post`s, you can not fetch a single attribute from taht...

Comment: posts.number is the current page number

Comment: @Abeselom: exactly, that is what you wanted to do with `{% if posts.number == num %}` right?